# Get the underlying network error if javascripts fetch throws

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I noticed that when fetch throws, it is very hard to get any additional information and what is going on.

For example if there is a CORS error or if you request from http, but the server only allows https origins, fetch just throws with this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Is there any way to retrieve the underlying network error, i.e. `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`?

Comment: I think due to security reasons `fetch` API intentionally limits the exposure of error details to prevent malicious websites from probing other websites and gathering information about their network errors. Also, wanted to know why would you require that since any approach would help you identify the issue but I doubt they give you exactly the n/w error code(for instance `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in your case)

Comment: I want to log if a user of the app does an action but fetch throws because of some firewall settings to debug issues with customers we have.